# MongoDB - Aggregate: How to group by depending on query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I want to aggregate over a collection where a type is given. The types come from query string and the can be day, month or year. Depending on what type the users chooses I want to group by. 
For example: If the user chooses "month" I want to group by month.

```
Event.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: { from: Product.collection.name, localField: 'product', foreignField: '_id', as: 'product' }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $month: { date: "$date" } },
        price: { $sum: "$price" },
        result: { $mergeObjects: { name: "$product.name", _id: "$product._id" } },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      },
    },
  ]).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    res.send(response)
  })
```

I can not figure it out how to find a clean solution. 
So far the only way I found was to use if conditional before Model.aggregate([])...

```
  if (req.query.dateAvailability && req.query.dateAvailability === 'month') {
    Event.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: { from: Product.collection.name, localField: 'product', foreignField: '_id', as: 'product' }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $month: { date: "$date" } },
          price: { $sum: "$price" },
          result: { $mergeObjects: { name: "$product.name", _id: "$product._id" } },
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        },
      },
    ]).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      res.send(response)
    })
  } else if (req.query.dateAvailability && req.query.dateAvailability === 'day') {
    Event.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: { from: Product.collection.name, localField: 'product', foreignField: '_id', as: 'product' }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$date" } },
          price: { $sum: "$price" },
          result: { $mergeObjects: { name: "$product.name", _id: "$product._id" } },
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        },
      },
    ]).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      res.send(response)
    })
  } else if (req.query.dateAvailability && req.query.dateAvailability === 'year') {
    Event.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: { from: Product.collection.name, localField: 'product', foreignField: '_id', as: 'product' }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $year: { date: "$date" } },
          price: { $sum: "$price" },
          result: { $mergeObjects: { name: "$product.name", _id: "$product._id" } },
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        },
      },
    ]).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      res.send(response)
    })
  }
```

Model Event:

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({

  client: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Client'
    }]
  },

  product: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product'
    }]
  },

  date: {
    type: Date,
    maxlength: 64,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true
  },

  place: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 1200,
    minlength: 1,
  },

  price: {
    type: Number
  },

  comment: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 12000,
    minlength: 1,
  },

  status: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    default: 0,
    validate: {
      validator: Number.isInteger,
      message: '{VALUE} is not an integer value'
    }
  },
},
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you tom slabbaert and Josh Balcitis, both solutions worked perfect and are cleaner than mine (I tested them). Good to know that there is no magic solution to remove the logic in this case also. I will accept tom's answer just because it was first, but both are a good approach make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic solution to remove the use of logic, In cases like this it will always be required.

However we can make the code a little sexier:

```
let groupCond;
if (req.query.dateAvailability && req.query.dateAvailability === 'month') {
    groupCond = { $month: { date: "$date" } };
} else if (req.query.dateAvailability && req.query.dateAvailability === 'day') {
    groupCond = { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$date" } };
} else if (req.query.dateAvailability && req.query.dateAvailability === 'year') {
    groupCond =  { $year: { date: "$date" } };
}

Event.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: { from: Product.collection.name, localField: 'product', foreignField: '_id', as: 'product' }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: groupCond,
            price: { $sum: "$price" },
            result: { $mergeObjects: { name: "$product.name", _id: "$product._id" } },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        },
    },
]).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    res.send(response)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic bullet to your problem the logic has to happen somewhere. Either with an if statement outside the query or a [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator inside the query if you are using a version of mongodb 3.4 or greater.

```
{"$group": {
  "_id":{ 
    "$switch": { 
      "branches": [
        { "case":{ "$eq": [ { "$literal": "day" }, { "$literal": req.query.dateAvailability } ] },
         "then": { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$date" } } },
        { "case":{ "$eq": [ { "$literal": "month" }, { "$literal": req.query.dateAvailability } ] },
         "then": { $month: { date: "$date" } } },
        { "case":{ "$eq": [ { "$literal": "year" }, { "$literal": req.query.dateAvailability } ] },
         "then": { $year: { date: "$date" } } }
      ], 
      "default": { ... default logic for when dateAvailability isn't set ... } 
    } 
  }
  ... rest of the group operation
} }
```